# real escape string to multiple connection

Tags: php, mysql, connection-string

it is possible to have multiple connection for one variable in real_escape_string?

my problem is that i need to insert the same `$_POST` into two diferent DB.

please see here:

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
$con2=mysqli_connect("localhost2","my_user2","my_password2","my_db2");



// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $con2, $_POST['username']);
mysqli_close($con, $con2);
?>
```

Comment: Instead of using real_escape_string (which is not foolproof), just use prepared statements/parameter binding and you won't have to worry about which connection it's going to use.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: hi @aynber, i'm a noob here so can you help me a little more?

Comment: See first: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: Escaping against two different connection handles only would make sense if connection and table charsets were different, btw.

Comment: Hi @mario, yes I have two completely different tables and connections

Comment: The answer to your question is: **no**.

Comment: Thank you @mario , I'm reading your link!